# Placing multiple markers on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm a little novice in JS, I'm trying to loop through some coordinates from nodes and place it on Google maps.

this is my code

```
var lis = document.getElementById("showNames").getElementsByTagName("li");
var lat = document.getElementById("showLat").getElementsByTagName("li");
var lng = document.getElementById("showLng").getElementsByTagName("li");
var length = lis.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i].innerHTML, lng[i].innerHTML),
        icon: '/panasonic/images/store-icons.png'
    }).setMap(map);

}
```

This does not work, I get an empty map but firebug shows no errors.

If I do this outside the loop

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0].innerHTML, lng[0].innerHTML),
    icon: '/panasonic/images/store-icons.png'
    //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
}).setMap(map);
```

However I need it loop through as I will be updating from my DB

Thanks

Comment: What your `lis`, `lat` and `lng` contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the below example. I have an array of coordinates which appear on the map when you click the "Add Some Markers" link.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
                ],
                demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
                map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, 
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
            <a href="#" class="add-markers">Add Some Markers</a>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated answer to show the markers automatically:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
                ],
                demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
                map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, 
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                initialize();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I show the markers without using the click function using your code? Show markers automatically on page load.